# Why $(a,b) \subsetneq \cup_{n=1}^\infty (a_n, b_n)$ where $a_n$ is decreasing to $a$ and $b_n$ strictly increases to $b$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, real-numbers

Why $(a,b) \subsetneq \cup_{n=1}^\infty (a_n, b_n)$ where $a_n$ is decreasing to $a$ and $b_n$ strictly increases to $b$.
I cant show why do we need to include the point $b_n$ ie the following holds
$(a,b) \subseteq \cup_{n=1}^\infty (a_n, b_n]$. I guess it has something to do with b strictly increasing but I cant reason why we absolutely need to include the point $b_n$.

Say for example if we take some $x \in (a,b)$ such that $x+\epsilon=b$ then for any arbitrary epsilon  we have the existence of an interval $(a_n,b_n)$ which contains $x$ since b_n strictly increases to $x$.

I am trying to show that for two sequence of rationals $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$, $(b_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ which are decreasing and strictly increasing to rationals $a$ and $b$ respectively
we have that 
$$
(a,b)=\cup_{n=1}^\infty (a_n, b_n]
$$
and I cannot explain why the point $b_n$ is needed on the RHS.

Comment: What is the asserting source? We don't need $b_n$. Actually we have automatically $b_n\in(a_{n+1},b_{n+1})$ for every $n$.

Comment: Probability essentials theorem 2.1 by jean Jacod jacod and Phillip Protter . There are almost no mistakes in the book which makes me wonder what am I missing

Comment: We don't need $b_n$ at all. We could also write it as a union of open intervals. This way we at least see that an open interval is open in the left pointed Sorgenfrey topology too.

Answer (score 2):

Both
$$
(a,b)=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty (a_n, b_n)\qquad\text{and}\qquad
(a,b)=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty (a_n, b_n]
$$
are true under your conditions.  I assume your source wanted to prove the second one for some purpose of its own.  For example, maybe they were doing measure theory in a way that starts with intervals of the form $(a,b]$.

Comment: Yes, most debelopments of Lebesgue measure start with the half-open half-closed intervals because they form a semiring or some such family.

Comment: Aha that explains it all . As a matter of fact I showed both but I couldn’t reconcile with the fact that the two countable unions were same . Thank you for you quick answer